# BigCommerce PHP Include

Tags: php, mysql, bigcommerce

We have a network of Bigcommerce sites, on which we've installed several tools that are controlled by one central site, using Bigcommerce's include feature. The url passes a get value to the php, and retrieves all of the pertinent information in our DB and displays several things.

The problem is that, as of last night, all of the 40-some sites began displaying content from the newest user - the newest DB entry. I deleted the newest user, and it reverted to the user just before that.

The weird part is that when I check the url being included, the correct information is displayed.

Check it out (I've stripped out most css and js, so most relevant info is shown) -
Site URL: http://www.epicflowers.us/
Included URL: http://epicflowers.com/toolbox/fetchToolbox2/toolbox.php?store_id=123456789

The colors and the text should be exactly the same. It appears that the DB queries are returning the correct information, but the site including the url are not.

**What I've already tried:**

- Duplicating and renaming files, in case it was a caching issue.
- Ran an ajax call to retrieve the same info (which worked, but it's too slow)

This didn't seem to happen as a result of changing anything, and the PHP side seems to be working fine. No one has touched the code in a few days, but the support tickets started coming in early this morning. It's altogether possible that it's completely unique to BigCommerce.

Any ideas?

**Update:**

It appears the BC include is ignoring the get values at the end of the url, so http://epicflowers.com/toolbox/fetchToolbox2/toolbox.php?store_id=123456789 appears as http://epicflowers.com/toolbox/fetchToolbox2/toolbox.php, obviously negating anything unique about the store the code is on.

Any ideas on why? Bigcommerce hasn't published anything in their blog that suggests this has changed.